# Black space in bottom of screen when focusing on TextField

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have trouble with black space on bottom of screen when focusing on text field.

Target application device has phisical keyboard (Zebra MC2700)

The problem occurs when I turn off the virtual keyboard and it looks like the system is showing me a black space at the bottom of the UI overlay. Zaznaczam, że ​​aplikacja działa w trybie pełnoekranowym.

Code of TextField:

```
          TextField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  labelText: 'ENTER PIN'
              ),
              obscureText: true,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
```

Black space appears when i entering Text Field and disappears when i unfocus it.

Before focus
[screen before focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5vIO.png)

After focus
[screen after focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uXOt.png)

Problem appears

Comment: Please provide a minimal code snippet of your problem.

Comment: @pawlituran share your code

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil i added code of my TextField

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the border of textField by

```
 TextField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 border: InputBorder.none,
  )
)
```

or you can make the TextField isCollapsed to true by

```
 TextField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 isCollapsed: true,
  )
)
```

Comment: Hey this not solve my problem i added more detailed description of my problem. Look at edited version of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it helpful :

Declare TextEditing Controller :

```
final TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
```

Then create your widget:

```
TextFormField(
        controller: username,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Username',
          hintText: 'Enter Username',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      ),
```

Comment: Hey this not solve my problem i added more detailed description of my problem. Look at edited version of my question.